# How do i get the call stack/caller of the method defined as pointcut when the advice is applied in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have method in a class which is getting called from various other methods.
I have created a pointcut for this method and the around advice logs all the execution details of this method like current execution time, max execution time etc. or any exceptions.

```
    <bean id="performanceMonitor"
          class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />

    <bean id="perfInterceptor" class="com.aop.PerformanceInterceptor"/>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allRestTemplate" expression="execution(* org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="allRestTemplate" advice-ref="perfInterceptor" order="2"/>
    </aop:config>
```

Here is the interceptor:

```
public class PerformanceInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return method.proceed();
        } catch (IOException | RestClientException ex){
            LOG.error("method " + method.getMethod().getName() + "for call from...??? ");
           throw ex;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I want to know which method is calling the pointcut method so that i can may be log it or group the execution stats based on the callers.

How to get the caller's name using spring AOP?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually from an AOP perspective, no application method is "calling the pointcut". The pointcut is activated by the aspect framework based on your pointcut whenever the pointcut matches a method execution.

As for how to get a call stack, this is not an AOP question, rather a basic Java question. Just use `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` and iterate over the array of `StackTraceElement`s. On Java 9+ there also is the [StackWalking API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-stackwalking-api).